# ODBC no longer works after server upgraded to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: sql-server, windows, odbc

We had SQL Server running on WIndows 10 Home and had a couple pf PC's that were connected to the server via ODBC. To facilitate automatic backup of the server we need to have Window 10 Pro on the server.  But after we upgraded the ODBC links to SQL server no longer work, and give the message "......Server does not exist or access is denied"  User name and passwords have not changed and I can ping the server with the IP address, but not the computer name.  We have no clue.

Thanks

Comment: Do you require NetBIOS for name resolution?  If so, is it disabled?

Comment: related? https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2033934-why-won-t-windows-10-pro-let-me-create-a-new-odbc